# How to call block content from HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this piece of code inside a .rb file:

```
main_content_blocks do
  5.times.map do |position|
    {
      id:                     rand(10..100),
      position:               position,
      block_type:             'text',
      text_markdown:          "**This is the Markdown number #{position}**",
      library_image_id:       nil,
      library_image_alt_text: nil,
      library_image_title:    nil,
      library_image_caption:  nil,
    }
  end
end
```

From HTML, for example within a Paragraph, I need to call the different options of the  main_content_blocks ... for example ID, text_markdown etc ...
How do I write the HTML with ruby <% %> ?

Comment: You can run this block inside your html template as long as you define main_content_blocks as an instance variable in your controller.  You would use the <%=  tag to output what you need in your view.

Comment: Hi  bkunzi01, thanks for your answer. As said I'm new to ruby. All the controller and mambo jambo has been already done. I need the HTML bit. Can you provide here hot to target (for example) text_markdown? <%= main_content_blocks.text_markdown %> perhaps?

Comment: Which .rb file and which function contains this code? As @bkunzi01 said, You need to have this as an instance variable in the controller within the corresponding action - like `@main_content_blocks = main_content_blocks do ...` - have you actually tried outputting the main_content_blocks ruby code? There are several errors in the ruby code there, starting with `undefined variable main_content_blocks`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a little more on bkunzi01's response - To get access to the main_content_blocks variable in your view after you make it in your controller simply add an `@` to the beginning of the variable needed,  this will make it an instance variable. for example if you were hitting your ExampleController#index route.

`controllers/example_controller.rb`

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @view_data =
       main_content_blocks do
         5.times.map do |position|
           {
            id:                     rand(10..100),
            position:               position,
            block_type:             'text',
            text_markdown:          "**This is the Markdown number #{position}**",
            library_image_id:       nil,
            library_image_alt_text: nil,
            library_image_title:    nil,
            library_image_caption:  nil,
           }
          end
       end 
   end
end
```

then in the view (using html and erb)

`views/example/index.html.erb`

```
<div>
   <% @view_data.each do |data| %>
      <h1><%= data[:id] %></h1>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

would render some thing like the following:

```
<div>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <h1>3</h1>
  <h1>4</h1>
  <h1>5</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Rails is smart enough to know when your route goes to `ExampleController#index` the view that needs to be rendered is located in `views/example/index.html`  without you needing to explicitly tell it.  Any instance variable set in the controller method will be available in its corresponding view by using erb syntax:    <% @something %> will not display something, but it will evaluate it.  <%= @something %> will display the value of the variable